# How should I got about re-creating a melody in chiptune?

Tags: chords, composition, performance-practice, modern-music

I am trying to recreate "[Pure Vessel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQ71AUNdjL0)"(A.K.A. Path of Pain theme) by Christopher Larkin in chiptune. However, my first attempt at it was awful([my failed attempt](http://tinyurl.com/PathOfPain8-bit)), and I would appreciate it if I could get some advice about re-creating it.

I have tried listening and then inputting, but apparently my ears for re-mixing by just listening don't get the job done. I've also tried searching for other people remixing it, but apparently I'm the first person to attempt this(at least, that is what I think)

Comment: On a side note, there isn't a tag for chiptune, and I don't have enough rep to create tags.

Comment: Why don't you start with the [score](https://musescore.com/user/5174461/scores/3945831) and work your way from there? Unless you really want to pick it up by ear.

Comment: @Pyromonk - Unless the score came directly from the game's composer(s)/developers/publisher(s)/game file, never completely trust a score for a video game theme. Keep using the original as a resource. I've found some video game theme transcriptions from published books that missed out many notes, and websites that accept regular users' content are caveat emptor.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, that much is obvious. But it's a good place to start.

Comment: @Pyromonk Thanks for the score! Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of instruments. I only know beepbox. I'm sure I can easily find online tutorials though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here doesn't appear to be anything to do with chiptune. The notes playing in your sample are just not the notes in the original. I am interested in how you are trying to identify the notes and the key the original is played in.

A solution my son uses when creating remixes and he isn't sure is to play part of the music, and sing the root note into mobile tuner app. Then he'll do the same with the other notes in the chord until he thinks he has them all. And then he'll play that chord and compare with the original.

It doesn't necessarily help him identify the key straight away - a few more chords helps him get that - but he gets all the notes correct rapidly.

Comment: I'll try an app that accomplishes this later. Thanks for the help, but how come it doesn't have anything to do with chiptune?

Comment: If you try and create notes in any other application, or with a synth, I would imagine you would have the same issue. I can hear the notes you have written, and I can hear how different they are from the original. That would be the same in another app.

Comment: Are you suggesting I use a website(or app) like this one? https://www.scales-chords.com/live-chord-sound-finder/

Comment: I wouldn't specify a particular one, but any note/tuner app should work just fine.Personally, I use a guitar, but that is because I know my way around one. My son hasn't the same experience with an instrument so the tuner app works well for him - it may well work for you.